# IndexError: list index out of range in python while something not found

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, loops, for-loop

How to Fix `IndexError: list index out of range`

I'm Doing Scraping But if My Script Can't Find Something It Give This Error

`IndexError: list index out of range`

I Want To Continue to next link not break but my script break and not go with second url

Here is my **python code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

plus = "+ "

with open("Sans Fransico.csv","r") as s:
    s.read()

df = pd.read_csv('Yelp+Scraping_Sans+Fransico.csv') # Get all the urls from the excel
mylist = df['Urls'].tolist() #urls is the column name

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for url in mylist:

    driver.get(url)
    wevsite_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .link-size--default__373c0__1skgq")
    phone = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_")



    items = len(wevsite_link)
    with open("Sans Fransico.csv", 'a',encoding="utf-8") as s:
        for i in range(items):
            if wevsite_link[i].text == '':
                s.write(phone[i].text + "\n")
            if [i] == '':
                s.write('N' + "," + 'N' + "\n")
                s.write('N' + "," + 'N' + "\n")
            if wevsite_link[i].text == '' and phone[i].text == '':
                s.write('' + "," + '' + "\n")
            else:
                s.write(phone[i].text + "," + wevsite_link[i].text + "\n")

driver.close()
print ("Done")
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\seleniuminform.py", line 36, in <module>
    s.write(phone[i].text + "," + wevsite_link[i].text + "\n")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Which line has IndexError? You can print len(wevsite_link)

Comment: This line `            if [i] == '':
                s.write('N' + "," + 'N' + "\n")
                s.write('N' + "," + 'N' + "\n")`

Comment: @UsmanShahzad this is unlikely, post thee stack trace.

Comment: Okay Wait i'm posting

Comment: @Guy Question Updated Please Check!

Comment: @Guy In Which Version Your Answer Work?

Comment: @Guy 3.5 or 3.7 or higher

Comment: @HamzaLachi f-string works with Python 3.6 and higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing items are not empty string, they don't exist. You can use `itertools.zip_longest` to iterate over both lists

```
with open("Sans Fransico.csv", 'a',encoding="utf-8") as s:
    for combination in itertools.zip_longest(wevsite_link, phone):
        s.write(f'{combination[0].text if combination[0] else "N"}, {combination[1].text if combination[1] else "N"}\n')
```

Comment: @UsmanShahzad I'm not sure what you are trying to check in `if [i] == '':`, but it creates a list with int, you are checking if this list is equal to `''`.

Comment: it's for if both is none than type none

Comment: It's working But Not Writing phone for example if some page had phone number but no website then he need to write phone and skip website but it's skiping phone and aslo website

Comment: But it's going to Next Url

Comment: But i also need to write some thing for example if website or phone is not there then he need not blank but if phone is not there and website is there he need to write website and skip phone

Comment: @UsmanShahzad Are you sure `wevsite_link[i].text` is `''` if the website doesn't exists? I think in that case `wevsite_link` is an empty list.

Comment: @UsmanShahzad *it's for if both is none than type none*, it doesn't check this, as I wrote in the first comment it check if a `list` is equal to `''` which will always be false.

Comment: Wait Let me Try!

Comment: What This Line Do? `if phone[i]:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201872/discussion-between-usman-shahzad-and-guy).

Answer (score 2):

if the errors are expected, you can wrap your main loop in a try/except´:

```
try:
   for url in mylist:
        .....

except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

That will let you keep going and still give you info about where errors occured.

Comment: it close my browser and print error but that is not solution i want to continue to next url

Comment: try it with a "pass" instead of printing the Exception. Does that leave your Browser open?